# How to extract individual tensors from a batch of tensors?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to upsample a bilateral grid using a guidance map (following [this](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/hdrnet/data/hdrnet.pdf) research paper).

I have created a Keras layer which takes 3 inputs and will provide the upsampled image:

1. BilateralGrids of shape (None, 16, 16, 96)
2. GuidanceMaps of shape (None, 256, 256)
3. InputImages of shape (None, 256, 256, 3)

Here, 'None' is the batch size which will be decided at runtime.

My motive is to perform pixel-wise computations as follows:

```
def slicing(BilateralGrids, GuidanceMaps, InputImages):
  output_images = []
  for i in range(batchSize):
    grid = BilateralGrids[i]
    guide = GuidanceMaps[i]
    input_img = InputImages[i]

    output = performPixelwiseComputation(grid, guide, input_img)
    #output.shape => (256, 256, 3)
    output_images.append(output)

  return output_images #output_images.shape => (BatchSize, 256, 256, 3)
```

The problem is we cannot run a loop over batch size since it is unknown.

I tried following things but nothing solved the problem:

1. Initially I thought lambda layer will provide inputs one by one, but it provides the complete batch.
2. Then I tried zip() in python, but it cannot work on tensors. [**I need exactly something like zip()**]
3. I tried tf.stack(), but it needs all the shapes and ranks of the tensors to be exactly same (which is not possible in my case)

PS: This is my first StackOverflow question. I apologize if it is not asked in an ideal way.

Comment: Is there no way that `performPixelwiseComputation` can be used on the whole batch at once using tensorflow ops? Otherwise, this seems to me like a good opportunity to write your own kernel and design whatever operation you need on the whole batch.

Comment: @Sunreef No, tensorflow default ops do not work for me. The pielwiseComputation need to access each pixel from each of the inputs, and since they are of different dimensions I need to write my own computation.

I do not have any idea or experience about writing our own kernel. I have seen some code in C++ which created their kernel, but other than tracking the flow of code I was not able to understand the working. Can you please forward me to some links where I can find more information about that. Also, can we write our kernel in Keras or tensorflow, or we must work in C++ for that?

Comment: Do you require that the batch size to be unknown to the function? Can you use a fixed batch size like 32 or so?

Comment: I would prefer it to be unknown and decided at runtime, but for testing purpose, I can try with a fixed batch size.

Can you tell how to fix a batch size, as I thought it was internally taken care by keras, and we do not have a control on that.

Comment: @AparSinghal  To create your own operation in C++, I found [Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) to be informative enough.

Comment: Okay, I will go through it and update if it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `tf.py_func`, [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func)

Basically, you need to write a custom function to cover your need. However, tensorflow is a symbolic framework. That prevents you to declare custom operations as you write normal python. You can access, modify and do whichever operation that you want to do through py_func 'hack'. However, you also may need to define back-propagation layer and calculations if you have any decision algorithms in ff network. Also, it is quite tricky and hard to debug this approach.

Alternatively, try a define-by-run framework like Chainer. So that, you can run your network as you type.